# Visiting a cousin in Belgium

Tags: visas, schengen, belgium, bangladeshi-citizens

I am planning to visit Belgium to see my cousin who has a Belgian passport.
He sent formal invitation Annexe 3, his salary certificate and family composition.

I have a Bangladesh passport, living in Abu Dhabi with a UAE residence visa since 2007.
My employer gave NOC to the Belgian embassy in the UAE. I am also submitting my bank statement with the application. I will stay there for 10 days.

Kindly note that in 2015 I applied for a tourist visa for Italy and I got rejected.

Please advise me how the Annexe 3 obligation will help to get the visa under the visiting friends and family category.

Do I need any other additional document from my side?

Comment: What was the reason for the earlier rejection for Italy?

Answer (score 1):

The website for [Belgium’s Office des Etrangers](https://dofi.ibz.be/sites/dvzoe/FR/Guidedesprocedures/Pages/Regroupement_familial/Les%20moyens%20de%20subsistance%20stables,%20r%C3%A9guliers%20et%20suffisants.aspx) refers to [Annexe 3bis](https://dofi.ibz.be/sites/dvzoe/NL/Documents/bijlage_03_02.pdf) as an alternative to proof of regular and sufficient means of subsistance (moyens de subsistance stables, réguliers et suffisants).

That would relieve you of providing your bank statement, but not of any other documents you’ve been asked to include in your visa application (e.g., itinerary, flight tickets, health insurance, employment, NOC). As you are also being offered accommodation, your cousin would want to provide a letter of invitation which states the relationship between you, the purpose of your visit, when you will stay (the dates), and where (the address).